# C# TreeView OnDrawNode is working slow and creating artifact

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, treeview

I am working on a custom C# TreeView and I would like to do some custom draw to highlight the keywords appear in the name of nodes.

I did :

```
DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
```

in the constructor of the custom TreeView and override the OnDrawNode:

```
protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Node.IsVisible) { return; }
        if (e.Node.Bounds.IsEmpty) { return; }

        e.DrawDefault = false;

        ...draw calls...
```

But it worked strangely after I coded like this, the perceived behaviors include:

1. OnDrawNode being call on the child nodes which is not expanded and invisible
2. When the content of the TreeView updates, the user would see the old content and new content at the same time overlapping with each other. The old content would disappear not until about half second or longer.
3. The rendering speed is much slower than the original draw call.

Another modification I did is the code snippet I found here to suppress the flickering happens when the TreeView is updating:
http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/double-buffered-tree-and-list-views
But it seems not directly related to the problem since I can still see the text overlapping after removing it.

I wonder if anyone have any idea about this issue?

Any thought would be appreciated.
Thank you.

edit:

The content of the OnDrawNode is like:

```
string pattern = keyword;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pattern))
{
    Regex regularExpressionnew = Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regularExpression.Match(e.Node.Text);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        CaptureCollection captureCollection = match.Groups[0].Captures;
        foreach (Capture capture in captureCollection)
        {
            int highlightStartIndex = capture.Index;
            int highlightEndIndex = capture.Index + pattern.Length;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(nodeHightLightColor, GetTextBoundsBetweenIndex(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, highlightStartIndex, highlightEndIndex, e.Bounds));
        }
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }

Brush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, Font, drawBrush, e.Bounds);
```

GetTextBoundsBetweenIndex is essentially calculating the square area covering the characters between highlightStartIndex and highlightEndIndex.

But the lag and overlap would happen event the regular expression is commented out and only the text rendering left.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.